# ms-access 2010: count duplicate names per household address

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am currently working with a spreadsheet in MS Access 2010 which contains about 130k rows of information about people who voted in a local election recently. Each row has their residential information (street name, number, postcode etc.) and personal information (title, surname, forename, middle name, DOB etc.). Each row represents an individual person rather than a household (therefore in many cases the same residential address appears more than once as more than one person resides in a particular household).

What I want to achieve is basically to create a new field in this dataset called 'count'. I want this field to give me a count of how many different surnames reside at a single address.

Is there an SQL script that will allow me to do this in Access 2010?

```
+------------------+----------+-------+---------+----------+-------------+
| PROPERTYADDRESS1 | POSTCODE | TITLE | SURNAME | FORENAME | MIDDLE_NAME |
+------------------+----------+-------+---------+----------+-------------+
 FAKEADDRESS1        EEE 5GG    MR      BLOGGS    JOE           N         
 FAKEADDRESS2        EEE 5BB    MRS     BLOGGS    SUZANNE       P        
 FAKEADDRESS3        EEE 5RG    MS      SMITH     PAULINE       S
 FAKEADDRESS4        EEE 4BV    DR      JONES     ANNE          D
 FAKEADDRESS5        EEE 3AS    MR      TAYLOR    STUART        A
```

The following syntax has got me close so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(electoral.SURNAME)
FROM electoral
GROUP BY electoral.UPRN
```

However, instead of returning me all 130k odd rows, it only returns me around 67k rows. Is there anything I can do to the syntax to achieve the same result, but just returning every single row?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: It would help to post some sample data (made up data) of the relevant columns. Use http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Comment: Hi @Andre451 I have attached sample data to the original question. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Andre451 - I have edited the original question. I have come quite close to achieving my goal but not quite there yet. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
select *,
count(surname) over (partition by householdName)
from myTable
```

If you have only one column which contains the name,
ex: `Rob Adams`
then you can do this to have all the surnames in a different column so it will be easier in the select:

```
SELECT LEFT('HELLO WORLD',CHARINDEX(' ','HELLO WORLD')-1)
```

in our example:

```
select right (surmane, charindex (' ',surname)-1) as surname
```

example on how to use charindex, left and right here:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17948.t-sql-right-left-substring-and-charindex-functions.aspx

if there are any questions, leave a comment.

EDIT: I edited the query, had a syntax error, please try it again. This works on sql server.

here is an example:

```
create table #temp  (id int, PropertyAddress varchar(50), surname varchar(50), forname varchar(50))
insert into #temp values 
(1, 'hiddenBase',  'Adamns' , 'Kara' ),
(2, 'hiddenBase',  'Adamns' , 'Anne' ),
(3, 'hiddenBase',  'Adamns' , 'John' ),
(4, 'QueensResidence',  'Queen' , 'Oliver' ),
(5, 'QueensResidence',  'Queen' , 'Moira' ),
(6, 'superSecretBase', 'Diggle' , 'John' ),
(7, 'NandaParbat',  'Merlin' , 'Malcom' )

select * from #temp

select *, 
count (surname) over (partition by PropertyAddress) as CountMembers
from #temp
```

gives:

```
1   hiddenBase  Adamns  Kara    3
2   hiddenBase  Adamns  Anne    3
3   hiddenBase  Adamns  John    3
7   NandaParbat Merlin  Malcom  1
4   QueensResidence Queen   Oliver  2
5   QueensResidence Queen   Moira   2
6   superSecretBase Diggle  John    1
```

Your query should look like this:

```
select *, 
count (SURNAME) over (partition by PropertyAddress) as CountFamilyMembers
from electoral
```

**EDIT**

If over partition by isn't supported, then I guess you can get to your desired result by using `group by`

```
select *, 
    count (SURNAME) over (partition by PropertyAddress) as CountFamilyMembers
    from electoral 
group by -- put here the fields in the select (one by one), however you can't write group by *
```

Comment: Hello CM2K, the personal information is split up into different columns, so title, surname, forename, middle name and DOB are all in separate columns. The only one I am interested in is the surname as I want to find out how many different surnames are residing at one address. For some reason the syntax you sent over does not seem to be working in Access. Am I perhaps not inputting it correctly:       <pre> SELECT *,
COUNT (electoral.SURNAME) 
OVER PARTITION BY (electoral.PropertyAddress1); <code>

Comment: If you could edit your question and add some sample data, for me to test a bit. That would be great

Comment: Hi CM2K, I have attached a sample image of the dataset to the original question, hope this helps you. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I had a syntax error, please see my edited answer (ps , i am testing this on sql server 2012, should work in access too)

Comment: Hi CM2K, thank you for all your help so far, I will try this syntax and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hi @CM2K, I have tried your edited answer and there still appears to be some syntax issues. Are there some major differences between the way a syntax is written on SQL server 2012 and Access 2010? Thanks again

Comment: `over partition` exists only on Sql Server, not in Access.

Comment: @Andre451 , didn't know that.  @A.Culora I don't usually use Access. And it seems that the window function `over partition by` isn't supported.

Comment: Ahh I see, @Andre451 I have attached sample data to this original question if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

GROUP BY creates an **aggregate query**, so it's by design that you get fewer records (one per UPRN).

To get the count for each row in the original table, you can join the table with the aggregate query:

```
SELECT electoral.*, elCount.NumberOfPeople
FROM electoral 
INNER JOIN
(    
    SELECT UPRN, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfPeople
    FROM electoral
    GROUP BY UPRN
) AS elCount
ON electoral.UPRN = elCount.UPRN
```

Comment: nice solution, I like it more than mine:)

Answer (score 0):

Given the update I want to post another answer. Try it like this:

```
create table #temp2  ( PropertyAddress1 varchar(50), POSTCODE varchar(20), TITLE varchar (20), 
surname varchar(50), FORENAME varchar(50), MIDDLE_NAME varchar (50) )

insert into #temp2 values 
('FAKEADDRESS1', 'EEE 5GG', 'MR', 'BLOGGS', 'JOE', 'N'),
('FAKEADDRESS1', 'EEE 5BB', 'MRS', 'BLOGGS', 'SUZANNE', 'P'),
('FAKEADDRESS2', 'EEE 5RG', 'MS', 'SMITH', 'PAULINE', 'S'),
('FAKEADDRESS3', 'EEE 4BV', 'DR', 'JONES', 'ANNE', 'D'),
('FAKEADDRESS4', 'EEE 3AS', 'MR', 'TAYLOR', 'STUART', 'A')

select PropertyAddress1, surname,count (#temp2.surname) as CountADD
into #countTemp
from #temp2 
group by PropertyAddress1, surname

select * from #temp2 t2
left join #countTemp ct
on t2.PropertyAddress1 = ct.PropertyAddress1 and t2.surname = ct.surname
```

This yields:

```
PropertyAddress1        POSTCODE    TITLE   surname FORENAME    MIDDLE_NAME PropertyAddress1    surname CountADD
FAKEADDRESS1             EEE 5GG    MR      BLOGGS  JOE                N    FAKEADDRESS1        BLOGGS     2
FAKEADDRESS1             EEE 5BB    MRS     BLOGGS  SUZANNE            P    FAKEADDRESS1        BLOGGS     2
FAKEADDRESS2             EEE 5RG    MS      SMITH   PAULINE            S    FAKEADDRESS2        SMITH      1
FAKEADDRESS3             EEE 4BV    DR      JONES   ANNE               D    FAKEADDRESS3        JONES      1
FAKEADDRESS4             EEE 3AS    MR      TAYLOR  STUART             A    FAKEADDRESS4        TAYLOR     1
```

Comment: Hi CM2K, As oppose to counting the number of same surnames at the same address, I would like a count of the number of distinct surnames residing at the same address. E.g. in the answer you have just posted, the count next to mr and mrs bloggs would be 1 as they have a common surname and are residing at the same address. Does this make sense? Apologies for any confusion!